# Loss string when using python list

Tags: python, arrays

I am doing a merge string base on its coordinate. Below is my code:

```
def merge_algo(texts, texts_boxes):
    for i, (text_1, text_box_1) in enumerate(zip(texts, texts_boxes)):
        for j, (text_2, text_box_2) in enumerate(zip(texts, texts_boxes)):
            if j <= i:
                continue
            if calc_sim(text_box_1, text_box_2) < dist_limit:
                new_box = merge_boxes(text_box_1, text_box_2)            
                new_text = text_1 + ' ' + text_2
                texts[i] = new_text
                texts = np.delete(texts, j)
                #del texts[j]
                texts_boxes[i] = new_box
                del texts_boxes[j]
                return True, texts, texts_boxes
    return False, texts, texts_boxes
```

However, when I assign a new_text for texts[i], it losses part of the string:

```
new_text = 'Per Email version 12345@abcmail.com'
then texts[i] = 'Per Email version 1234'
```

It loses a part of the new text. Please show me any reason for that.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing with what parameters `texts` and `texts_boxes` you're actually calling the function `merge_algo`. Please provide example code that includes some test data and allows people to reproduce the issue.

Comment: texts and texts_boxes are an array to store text and its coordinates (which I extract from xml file) texts_boxes.append(s_coord)
 texts.append(s_text)

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example